# Authenticate with Google in a signed Android App

Tags: android, google-play-services

I'm trying to create an android app that [authenticates with Google account](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating).
After hours of struggling I see that when I remove the [Signing](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html) from my android app, the Google  authentication works perfectly; instead, when I Sign the application, suddenly it gives me an "Internal Error", hence I cannot authenticate with Google account.

For a better comprehension:
I Sign the app as below following [Android Developers Steps](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html).

[image]

With the signed App, the authentication with Google doesn't work.
If I remove the config that describes the Signin than I can normally authenticate with Google account, otherwise it's simply an internal error as follows:

[image]

I'm a complete newbie in android programming, so I'm asking here if anyone has some reference or input to give me in order that I can understand the problem and what to look for (I've been searching in the web but still now nothing matches my problem).

Thanks!

Comment: Please rephrase your first paragraph specially the second sentence. It is confusing because you said that the authentication works perfectly then later you said that you cannot authenticate. Also, provide the error in your logcat.

Comment: He means to say that if his apk is debug signed login is working, but it's not when release signed.

Comment: I provided some more information!

Comment: You have a key for debug version and a key for signed version. you need to enter the sign key in developer consol

Comment: @MaorHadad in which section/way of the developer console? because it seems not so obvious to me

Comment: the same way you use to get sha1 key with debug.keystore. just do it with release.keystore

Answer (score 0):

Are you using **release** google-services.json ? It should contain your release certificate SHA-1.
Probably you're using debug certificate SHA-1, if that's the case, it will only work with debug signed apps. For release signed apps you should generate again google-services.json with the appropiate SHA-1.